# Parsing CSV / tab-delimited txt file with Python

Tags: python, parsing, csv, dictionary

I currently have a CSV file which, when opened in Excel, has a total of 5 columns. Only columns A and C are of any significance to me and the data in the remaining columns is irrelevant.

Starting on line 8 and then working in multiples of 7 (ie. lines 8, 15, 22, 29, 36 etc...), I am looking to create a dictionary with Python 2.7 with the information from these fields. The data in column A will be the key (a 6-digit integer) and the data in column C being the respective value for the key. I've tried to highlight this below but the formatting isn't the best:-

```
    A        B      C          D
1                           CDCDCDCD  
2                           VDDBDDB
3
4
5
6
7  DDEFEEF                   FEFEFEFE
8  123456         JONES
9
10
11
12
13
14
15 293849         SMITH
```

As per the above, I am looking to extract the value from A7 (DDEFEEF) as a key in my dictionary and "FEFEFEFE" being the respective data and then add another entry to my dictionary, jumping to line 15 with "2938495" being my key and "Smith" being the respective value.

Any suggestions? The source file is a .txt file with entries being tab-delimited.
Thanks

Clarification:

Just to clarify, so far, I have tried the below:-

```
import csv

mydict = {:}
f = open("myfile", 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

The above simply prints out all content though a row at a time. I did try "for row(7) in reader" but this returned an error. I then researched it and had a go at the below but it didn't work neither:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

entries = csv.reader(open("myfile", 'rb'))
mydict = {'key' : 'value'}

for i in xrange(6):
    mydict['i(0)] = 'I(2)    # integers representing columns
    range = islice(entries,6)
    for entry in range:
        mydict[entries(0) = entries(2)] # integers representing columns
```

Comment: @jdigital - original question edited to contain what I've tried so far

Comment: "starting on line 8" is not consistent with "A7", "6-digit integer" is not consistent with "DDEFEEF" -- please edit your question.

Comment: @John Machin - A7 is not the cell I want to extract the data from, it is A8. The data in A7 is simply just to give you an example of what other data exists in my CSV file. As it's not a 6-digit integer, it is to be ignored. Thanks

Comment: @thefragileomen: Try reading your own question: "I am looking to extract the value from A7 (DDEFEEF) as a key in my dictionary and "FEFEFEFE" being the respective data" -- as I said, inconsistent.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Start by turning the text into a list of lists.  That will take care of the parsing part:

```
lol = list(csv.reader(open('text.txt', 'rb'), delimiter='\t'))
```

The rest can be done with indexed lookups:

```
d = dict()
key = lol[6][0]      # cell A7
value = lol[6][3]    # cell D7
d[key] = value       # add the entry to the dictionary
 ...
```

Answer (score 10):

Although there is nothing wrong with the other solutions presented, you could simplify and greatly escalate your solutions by using python's excellent library pandas.

Pandas is a library for handling data in Python, preferred by many Data Scientists.

Pandas has a simplified CSV interface to read and parse files, that can be used to return a list of dictionaries, each containing a single line of the file. The keys will be the column names, and the values will be the ones in each cell.

In your case:

```
    import pandas

    def create_dictionary(filename):
        my_data = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(filename, sep='\t', index_col=False)
        # Here you can delete the dataframe columns you don't want!
        del my_data['B']
        del my_data['D']
        # ...
        # Now you transform the DataFrame to a list of dictionaries
        list_of_dicts = [item for item in my_data.T.to_dict().values()]
        return list_of_dicts

# Usage:
x = create_dictionary("myfile.csv")
```

Comment: As of pandas version 0.21.0, pandas.DataFrame.from_csv() has been deprecated. pandas.read_csv() can be used instead.

Answer (score 4):

If the file is large, you may not want to load it entirely into memory at once. This approach avoids that. (Of course, making a dict out of it could still take up some RAM, but it's guaranteed to be smaller than the original file.)

```
my_dict = {}
for i, line in enumerate(file):
    if (i - 8) % 7:
        continue
    k, v = line.split("\t")[:3:2]
    my_dict[k] = v
```

Edit: Not sure where I got `extend` from before. I meant `update`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've tried implementing the above and get a "ValueError" on the final line - "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required". Any suggestions?

Comment: @thefragileomen edited for a more readable approach that doesn't require three levels of braces to work ;)