# Reading file in python without tab separated

Tags: python, arrays

I want to read a tab separated file into a 2-D array where each line get stored in my 2-D array. I tried open and readline but nothing is working correct for me.
Lets say my txt file is something like this :

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5 6 
...
```

so what I want is my 2-D array should store `array[0]=[1,2,3,4]`, `array[1]=[2,3,4,5]` and so on.

Comment: how do you know to when to split the text file into a new array?

Comment: Please complete your question with code so that someone can understand better what you need...

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856296/parsing-csv-tab-delimited-txt-file-with-python)

```
import csv
list(csv.reader(open('text.txt', 'rb'), delimiter='\t'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is numerical data I suggest the following: use `numpy` like this

```
import numpy as np 

data = np.loadtxt('data.dat')
```

Optionally you can also specify a data type:

```
import numpy as np 

data = np.loadtxt('data.dat', dtype=np.float64)
```

If it is not numerical data, I would recommend `csv` like shown in the answer of CasualDemon:

```
import csv
list(csv.reader(open('data.dat', 'rb'), delimiter='\t'))
```