# In Python, how do you import web data with .data extension?

Tags: python, data-analysis

In python 3 I want to import web data with .data extension found in the link below. What's the code to import it?

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing CSV / tab-delimited txt file with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856296/parsing-csv-tab-delimited-txt-file-with-python)

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with it next. "machine learning database" suggests you plan to use a machine learning toolkit... so use its file reading services. Same goes for something like numerical analysis in `pandas`. The most generic parser is `csv` which just gives you rows as lists.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

Knowing the data structure, there’s 9 columns, so we need only 8 splits. Start with reading data:

```
with open('auto-mpg.data') as fp:
    data = [line.split(maxsplit=8) for line in fp]
```

Now you can handle each cell you’ve got.

This function must do the job:

```
import re

def handle(s):
    if s == '?':
        return None
    elif re.match(r'^\d+\.\d+$', s):
        return float(s)
    elif re.match(r'^\d+$', s):
        return int(s, 10)
    else:
        return s.strip().strip('"')

data = [tuple(map(handle, row)) for row in data]
```

Putting it all together:

```
import re

def handle(s):
    if s == '?':
        return None
    elif re.match(r'^\d+\.\d+$', s):
        return float(s)
    elif re.match(r'^\d+$', s):
        return int(s, 10)
    else:
        return s.strip().strip('"')

with open('auto-mpg.data') as fp:
    data = [
        tuple(map(handle, row))
        for row in (line.split(maxsplit=8) for line in fp)
    ]
```

But it all was possible just because we know the data structure.

Comment: You also can use `zip()` or a class constructor to process each tuple and give meaning to fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data')
```

This is what you get at the end (Auto-mpg Data on PyCharm Console):

[image: Auto-mpg Data on PyCharm Console]

Comment: You get an image?

Comment: No. You can also use `data.to_csv("mydata.csv", index=False, header=False)` to export the data as csv file.