# how to separate text and labels using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I am a newbie to NLP, I have a text with labels `0` and `1`.

How do I separate the labels and create a new column? Please help me.

Here is my text with labels:

```
Everything from acting to cinematography was solid.     1

Definitely worth checking out.      1            
I purchased this and within 2 days it was no longer working!!!!!!!!!    0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your source document may be a [tab-delimited file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856296/parsing-csv-tab-delimited-txt-file-with-python) but the formatting was changed when pasting into the SO window. If that's the case, then you should use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) package.

Assuming there are no special delimiter characters (such as `\t` or `,`) in between your text and labels, you could simply extract the label as the last non-whitespace for the line. For example...

```py
# suppose you read the file out as a gigantic string
text_and_labels = """
Everything from acting to cinematography was solid.     1

Definitely worth checking out.      1
I purchased this and within 2 days it was no longer working!!!!!!!!!    0
"""

data = []
lines = text_and_labels.split('\n')  # split each line
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()  # remove any outside whitespace
    if line == '':
        continue  # it's a blank line
    label = line[-1]  # the last non-whitespace character
    text = line[:-1].strip()  # everything else, without the extra whitespace
    data.append((text, label))
data[0]
>>> ('Definitely worth checking out.', '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

If file have proper formatted text than you do it with with simple file handling and proper indexing. else for bad formatted text you can go for regex.

```
file = open('filename','r+')
list1 = []
for line in file.readlines():
    try:
        list1.append(line[-2])
    except:
        pass
```

Now you can use this list for creating columns